# A title is not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment

The title "Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles" is not centered.  I issued the commands `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` and the command `\begin{centering} ... \end{centering}`.  How can I get the title centered?!

This is just a small sample from a file.  All the text is not horizontally centered on the page.  It is pushed to the right.  How do I get it horizontally centered?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{centering}\Large{\textbf{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}}\end{centering}\vskip0.3in



\noindent {\bf Definition} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
{\em $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$ are the initial and terminal sides of $\angle{AOB}$, respectively, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB} = \theta$, and $0 \leq \theta < 360^{\circ}$. If $\overline{OB^{\prime}}$ is the reflection of $\overline{OB}$ across the line containing $\overline{OA}$, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB^{\prime}} = -\theta$.}
\end{minipage}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent {\bf Trigonometric Identities} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \hspace*{1em}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
{\em For any real number $0 < \theta \leq 360$,}
\begin{equation*}
\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta
\qquad \mbox{\em{and}} \qquad
\sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta
\end{equation*}
{\em and so, for any such $\theta$ distinct from $90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$,}
\begin{equation*}
\tan(-\theta) = -\tan\theta .
\end{equation*}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bf` ought not be used in LaTeX documents created in the last 20+ years or so as it was deprecated with the introduction of LaTeX 2e.

Comment: @cfr  Yep.  It should be replaced with `\textbf{}`.

Comment: Or `\bfseries` if you want a switch. Is the Trigo... thing meant to be your title? Also `\Large` does not take an argument - it is a switch.

Comment: `  \begin{center}
    \Large\textbf{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}
  \end{center}
` will centre it, but if it is a heading or title, it should be marked up as such and not manually formatted. It still won't look centred, because the material in the main text is much too wide for the text width.

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V); [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: So much visual formatting. You should really be using sectioning commands, too, or defining one of your own. I have a `\heading` command that goes like this `\makeatletter
\newcommand\heading{\@startsection{subsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
{-1.625ex\@plus -.5ex \@minus -.1ex}%
{.75ex \@plus .1ex}%
{\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother`. Modify to taste.

Comment: why bother to use `amsart` if you're going to format everything manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using semantic markup for document elements rather than manually formatting. For example, if `Trigon...` is the title of your document, you want

```
\title{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}% if it is the title of the document
\author{}\date{}
\maketitle
```

or if it is the heading of a section, you need

```
\section{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}% if it is a section heading
```

or if the section should be unnumbered, you use

```
\section*{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}% if it is an unnumbered section heading
```

Similar points apply to definitions, etc. You want to configure your document so that you can say, for example

```
\begin{definition}{something}
  This is a definition of something.
\end{definition}
```

and have this code produce the format you want.

Packages such as `amsthm` and `ntheorem` can help you do this easily.

This ensures consistent formatting and makes it easy to change the format of, say, all definitions or all lemmas by altering a few options in the preamble.

There is not environment `centering`. `\centering` is a command.

```
\begin{center}
  Something centred with vertical spacing before and after.
\end{center}
{\centering Something centred without additional vertical spacing.\par}
```

Here's a full example which uses the facilities provided by `amsthm` (via `amsart`) to configure a `definition` environment, and a regular `\newenvironment` to create a `trig` environment. The syntax for `definition` is:

```
\begin{definition}
  Definition of something.
\end{defintion}
```

and for `trig`:

```
\begin{trig}{Heading}
  Whatever.
\end{trig}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}{2.5mm}{2.5mm}{\itshape}{0pt}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{#1}
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newenvironment{trig}[1]{%
  \vskip 2.5mm plus .2ex minus 1ex\par
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\par\noindent
  \itshape\ignorespaces}{}
\begin{document}
\title{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}
\author{}\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{definition}
  $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$ are the initial and terminal sides of $\angle{AOB}$, respectively, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB} = \theta$, and $0 \leq \theta < 360^{\circ}$. If $\overline{OB^{\prime}}$ is the reflection of $\overline{OB}$ across the line containing $\overline{OA}$, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB^{\prime}} = -\theta$.
\end{definition}

\begin{trig}{Trigonometric Identities}
  For any real number $0 < \theta \leq 360$,
    \begin{equation*}
      \cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta
      \qquad \mbox{\em{and}} \qquad
      \sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta
    \end{equation*}
    and so, for any such $\theta$ distinct from $90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$,
    \begin{equation*}
      \tan(-\theta) = -\tan\theta .
    \end{equation*}
\end{trig}    
\end{document}
```

[image: example with semantic markup]

## EDIT

In comments, you indicated that what you really want is to achieve something in line with AMS style. If so, then you should take a look at `amsart-template.tex` and the documentation for the AMS classes. `amsart.cls` provides three theorem styles: `theorem`, `remark` and `plain`. The template includes a handful of sample theorem definitions and further definitions should make use of the standard styles.

For example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
% to use standard AMS formatting, take code from amsart-template.textbf
% if appropriate, your document body should also reflect the structure of that template and follow the guidance provided in the comments there and the documentation
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% some additions to demonstrate the third style provided by amsart
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{comment}[theorem]{Comment}
\begin{document}
\title{Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles}
\author{}\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{definition}
  $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$ are the initial and terminal sides of $\angle{AOB}$, respectively, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB} = \theta$, and $0 \leq \theta < 360^{\circ}$. If $\overline{OB^{\prime}}$ is the reflection of $\overline{OB}$ across the line containing $\overline{OA}$, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOB^{\prime}} = -\theta$.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[something]
  This is a definition of `something'.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
  This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}[Aardvarks]
  This is a remark about aardvarks.
\end{remark}

\begin{comment}[Trigonometric Identities]
  For any real number $0 < \theta \leq 360$,
    \begin{equation*}
      \cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta
      \qquad \mbox{\em{and}} \qquad
      \sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta
    \end{equation*}
    and so, for any such $\theta$ distinct from $90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$,
    \begin{equation*}
      \tan(-\theta) = -\tan\theta .
    \end{equation*}
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

[image: AMS styling]

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I would like to have formatting more consistent with AMS style.  I have several questions on your preamble.  Here are two of them.  What is the `mytheorem` in  `\theoremstyle{mytheorem}`?  What is the `Definition` in `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}`?  I have the book LaTeX User's Guide and Reference Manual by Leslie Lamport ... but it is not readily available to me.  Is there a web site you can suggest to explain what you have in the preamble?

Comment: @user74973 It is using facilities provided by `amsart` which loads `amsthm`. Take a look at the templates in the documentation folder for the AMS classes. I based the code on the preamble suggested for the template, but adapted it to more closely match the look you seemed to want.

Comment: @user74973 Please see edit for an illustration of this approach. Note that the result looks less like the output from your original example because that code did not correspond to AMS style. If you want to adhere to that style, things are easier because the class, supporting packages and template code are all geared to that style and you don't need to worry about formatting details yourself at all.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I think that I prefer the code that you first provided, which gives a display more like the display that my code gives.  How do I look at the templates in the documentation folder for the AMS classes?

Comment: @user74973 Just look in the `doc/latex/amscls/` directory of your main TeX tree and open whichever `.tex` file you wish to examine in the editor of your choice. You will also find various PDFs and plain text files here.

Answer (score 3):

The `center` environment can be used for headings and will certainly center content with respect to the text block. This may not be the horizontal centre of the page. If that's what you're after, add

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

to your preamble where you specify a uniform `margin` (or `hmargin`).

It's better to define some structural element to manage your formatting, as it will allow you to maintain a consistent layout throughout your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{block}[1]
  {\par\medskip
   \noindent\textbf{#1}% Heading
   \par\noindent\ignorespaces
  }% \begin{block}{<heading>}
  {\par}% \end{block}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \Large\bfseries
  Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles
\end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{block}{Definition}
  $\overline{OA}$ and~$\overline{OB}$ are the initial and terminal sides of~$\angle{AOB}$, 
  respectively, $\mathrm{m}\angle{AOB} = \theta$, and $0 \leq \theta < 360^{\circ}$. 
  If~$\overline{OB'}$ is the reflection of~$\overline{OB}$ across the line containing~$\overline{OA}$, 
  $\mathrm{m}\angle{AOB'} = -\theta$.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Trigonometric identities}
  For any real number $0 < \theta \leq 360$,
  \begin{equation*}
    \cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta \qquad \text{and} \qquad
    \sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta
  \end{equation*}
  and so, for any such~$\theta$ distinct from $90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ}$,
  \begin{equation*}
    \tan(-\theta) = -\tan\theta.
  \end{equation*}
\end{block}

\end{document}
```

Above I defined a `block` environment that takes a single (mandatory) argument. This argument is set in **bold** as a "heading". If you want, you can add other formatting options here, like `\itshape` for *italics*.

Comment: But `Trigonometric Functions Evaluated at Negative Angles` almost certainly should not be manually formatted... ;).